# SATA HDD clunck heads on reboot and shutdown

Tags: debian, hard-disk, shutdown, reboot

On small NAS server based on DietPi (Debian 11), every time when I use the reboot or the shutdown command the heads of HDD's are making strong clunking noise and doesn't sound healthy. I'm pretty sure that for some reason the OS doesn't wait for the HDD heads to be parked properly.

How can I make sure both commands initiating parking sequence and wait for it?

Comment: How can you be pretty sure? There's no separate command for that, that's all built-in to the hard drive firmware nowadays. (Assuming this isn't a hard drive from the early 1980s)

Comment: Indeed, that 'clunking' sound may well be the sound of the heads _being_ parked.

Comment: I have few of the same HDDs on other systems and they doesn't make that noise during shutdown or reboot sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hdparm -y /dev/sdX` should be sufficient before shutdown.

For ease of mind, also run `umount /dev/sdX` beforehand, you'll likely have to write a script to manually stop all daemons that use your disk.

During reboots, all I can say is that it shouldn't happen, and there's nothing you can do about it that would wear your disk less. You may want to measure voltage of your power supply during reboot, it may be jumping and causing your disk to go through a procedure it does during a real power loss.